# SharePoint 2013 - How to remove name of subsite from all subsite page title elements

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a subsite I created within my sharepoint environment, but only want each of these subsite pages to reflect the name of the page, not the name of the subsite.  For example, I want  of each subpage to be...

```
<title>my custom page</title>
```

not...

```
<title>subsite name - my custom page</title>
```

how do we fix this?

what from here needs to change, in order to just get the custom page name...

```
    <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>-->
    <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldFieldValue" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
    <!--ME:</PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>-->
    <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
    <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

Comment: You may need to edit the master page. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I tried - there is nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the answer - simply remove the following sharepoint tag from the snippet (if you have it there) which should be in your custom page layouts...

```
   <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>-->
```

Or, if you don't want to modify the .htm code in your custom page layout, you can edit the **SEO properties** of each page from the ribbon, when you are in edit mode.  You can change the browser title, as well as other cool stuff like meta keywords and descriptions per page.  This is wonderful!