# Don't display subsite in search result title

Tags: search-results

My SharePoint 2013 Search Results are being returned with the name of the subsite included in the result title. For example, if a page is called "My Page Title" and the subsite is "My Subsite", the search result title is "My Subsite My Page Title".

What I would like to see is only the page title, eg, "My Page Title"

I've tried using the following metadata fields for title: 
- ows_Title  - "My Subsite My Page Title"
- TermTitle  - "My Subsite My Page Title"
- MetaDataExtractorTitle  - "My Subsite My Page Title"

Each of the above returns the same.

Is there a way to return only the page title in the search results?

Comment: What is the <title> of your pages?  Search may be indexing the original pages' TITLE tag and that already has the site name with the page name concatenated.  Thus, that field always has both names perhaps?

Comment: Thanks it's a good theory but the <title> is set to "My Page Title".

Comment: Be sure you are looking at the actual Title field and not the title rendered on the page.

Comment: Matthew your comment seems to be at the crux of the issue.   I looked and I've noticed that <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/>-->  is returning a page title with both the subsite and title, but  <!--MS:<SharePoint:FieldValue id="HeadTitle" FieldName="Title" RunAt="Server">-->  returns the expected title only.     So there is a Page Title and a Title, which are different, I didn't know.    Thanks! I'll keep investigating then mark your comment as answer.   Where does Page Title get set?

Comment: Solving the mystery is halfway to solving the problem.  Good luck.

Comment: I found it! Well, I found blachawk's answer to a different question, over at: 

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131526/sharepoint-2013-how-to-remove-name-of-subsite-from-all-subsite-page-title-elem

This ended up being the same solution to my problem.